# How to get the option text value after onchange it in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a select drop down,on change of 'Cities'  I am getting the value of previous selection not current selection values.For ex: here if I select state and again If I select Cities,the div text comes under state is showing in alert,but I want to show the div text comes under cities.Again I want to display all the value as a message one by one,here I can able to display last value only.Can any one please help me on these 2 issues.Here is the code below.

### HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select class="change" ng-model="x" ng-change="update()">
      <option value="city">Cities</option>
      <option value="state">States</option>
      <option value="country">Countries</option>
    </select>
    <div ng-repeat="emp in groups" class="test" ng-attr-id="{{emp[attr]}}"><p>{{emp[attr]}}</p></div>
    <div class="error">{{col}}</div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

### Script

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.groups = [{
      title: 'title1',
      name: 'name1',
      details: 'one'
    },
    {
      title: 'title2',
      name: 'name2',
      details: 'two'
    },
    {
      title: 'title3',
      name: 'name2',
      details: 'three'
    }
  ]
  $scope.update = function() {
    if ($scope.x == 'city') {
      $scope.id = 'city';
      $scope.attr = 'details';
      $('div.test').each(function(i,div){
      var listitem = div;
      $scope.col = $(div).find("p").text();
      alert($scope.col);
      });
      }



    if ($scope.x == 'state') {
      $scope.id = 'state';
      $scope.attr = 'title';
    }
    if ($scope.x == 'country') {
      $scope.id = 'country';
      $scope.attr = 'name';
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: If you are going to use jQuery with AngularJs include jQuery first. AngularJs checks if jQuery is loaded and uses jQuery lite if not. But the general rule is jQuery is bad m'kay.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code, the basic angularjs syntax looks correct and it works.

What you should think about is to avoid mixing jQuery and angularjs. What jQuery can do - You can do with angularjs, the angularjs way, you just need to learn it.

Here's an working example where I removed your jQuery stuff.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.groups = [{
      title: 'title1',
      name: 'name1',
      details: 'details1'
    },
    {
      title: 'title2',
      name: 'name2',
      details: 'details2'
    },
    {
      title: 'title3',
      name: 'name3',
      details: 'details3'
    }
  ]
  $scope.update = function() {
    if ($scope.id == 'city') {
      $scope.attr = 'details';
    }else if ($scope.id == 'state') {
      $scope.attr = 'title';
    }else if ($scope.id == 'country') {
      $scope.attr = 'name';
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select class="change" ng-model="id" ng-change="update()">
      <option value="city">Cities</option>
      <option value="state">States</option>
      <option value="country">Countries</option>
    </select>
    <div ng-repeat="emp in groups" class="test" ng-attr-id="{{emp[attr]}}"><p>{{emp[attr]}}</p></div>
    <div class="error">{{col}}</div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks but your code does not contains my answer which I asked here.